# how to know the name of the selected tab? (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a view model that control the click event of a button, the code is:

```
ucMantenimientoView miViewPlanificacion = new ucMantenimientoView();
ucMantenimientoViewModel miViewModelPlanificacion = new ucMantenimientoViewModel();
miViewPlanificacion.DataContext = miViewModelPlanificacion;
```

The view has a tab, and with MVVM Light I manage the click event on the view model of the selectedItem event of the tab control.

The problem is that I need to know which is the name of the selected tab in the creation of the view and the view model, but the selectedItem is not fire, by default is selected the first tab, so I don't know how can I get the name of the selected tab in the creation of the view model.

If I select another tab and later I select the first tab, then it works, but I need this data in the constructor of the view model.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of events, have you tried binding the `SelectedItem` property of the `TabControl` (assuming it has one) and watching that for changes in your VM? I am using Telerik control suite and that allows you to choose a `SelectedItemPath` which you can point to a property on the bound object - I use the `Tag` property of the tab item to store the tab name. You could also bind the `SelectedIndex` property - probably less explicit but if you can guarantee the tab order it's an option. Failing all that you could just force the event to fire manually or use an aggregator to send the data to the VM

Comment: Well, I thought in the option to miViewPlanificacion.MyTabCOntrol.SelectedItem but is not available the propierties of the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using WPF and MVVM and we want to know some value of a UI control, it is customary to simply data bind a view model property to that UI property. In this way, we always have the required data at our fingertips, right in the view model.

How you set up your `Binding` will depend on how you have set up your XAML. If you data bind the `TabControl.ItemsSource` like the example below, then you'd have the text from all of the `TabItem.Header` properties in the `YourTabItemData.HeaderText` properties:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourTabItemData}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderText}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Content -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Then you could just data bind an object of the relevant type to the `TabControl.SelectedItem` property and then you'd have access to the text in the `TabControl.Header` of the selected `TabItem`:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourTabItemData}" SelectedItem="{Binding YourItem}">
    ...
</TabControl>
```

...

```
public YourTabItemDataClass YourItem
{
    get { return yourItem; }
    set 
    {
        yourItem = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged(); 
        // Selected TabItem has just changed
        string headerOfSelectedTab = yourItem.HeaderText;
    }
}
```

However, if you are *not* data binding to the `TabControl.ItemsSource` property, then there is a much simpler solution. You can set the `SelectedValuePath` property to return the `Header` value from the selected `TabItem` and then data bind to the `SelectedValue` property to get the actual value:

```
<TabControl SelectedValue="{Binding Selected}" SelectedValuePath="Header">
    <TabItem Header="HeaderOne" Name="NameOne"></TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="HeaderTwo" Name="NameTwo"></TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

You could even use parts of both solutions depending on what suits you.

> Disclaimer:
>   I just assumed that you meant `Header` when you said `Name`, but if you really meant `Name`, then this solution would work just as well if you simply replace all occurrences of `Header` with `Name`.

Comment: Yes, really I mean "name" instead of "header", but is the same, thanks.

Comment: Haha... yeah sorry, that just occurred to me about half way through my answer.